# How to display all dates between 2 dates in a column?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a 16 000 rows excel file, I've checked for the past few days on the internet but didn't find any relevant help to this particular problem.

The idea is that 2 columns (H and I) include starting date and end date for up to 365 lines (corresponds to 365 following days). For each line I'd like to write each date from start date to end date.
For example, my first 10 lines include a start date of 01/01/2018 and end date of 01/10/2018. For each line, i'd like to have each date as follows:

- 01/01/2018
- 01/02/1018
- 01/03/2018
- ...
- 01/10/2018

My main issue is that it should stop on the 10th line if the value of the cell equals to the date of 'end date' (if that can help, I have a 'number of days' columns which is the difference between end date and start date in column K)

You'll find below my current codes. As I'm a beginner, it includes a fewmistakes. Can you please provide me with some help?

```
    Sub Dates()
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count
    FirstDate = Cells("8" & Rows.Count).Value
    LastDate = Cells("9" & Rows.Count).Value
    NbDays = Cells("11" & Rows.Count).Value

    For X = Cells("2" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown) To LastRow
            If FirstDate = LastDate Then
                X = FirstDate

    Else
        Do
            X = FirstDate + 1

        Loop Until X.Value = LastDate

    End Sub
```

Spreadsheet should look as follows:

```
    Type    Date     Start date   End Date
    A   01/01/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/02/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/03/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/04/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/05/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/06/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/07/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/08/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/09/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    A   01/10/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018
    B   02/06/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018
    B   02/07/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018
    B   02/08/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018
    B   02/09/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018
    B   02/10/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018
```

I thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure where PHP fits in here.

Comment: Create a pivottable and use the filter between on dates?

Comment: @NigelRen My bad

Comment: @QHarr That would be an idea but I'd like to be able to automate this action to various kinds of files. VBA seems to be easier to transpose to all files

Comment: `Cells` does not use a string:  cell `H1` is `Cells(1,8)`, cell `J1` is `Cells(2,10)` etc

Comment: @Chronocidal Thanks, should I use Range instead?

Comment: You can use either of `Range("H" & Rows.Count)` or `Cells(Rows.Count, 8)` - I would usually recommend `Cells(..)` because it is *so* much easier for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going recommend a `FOR` loop, taking advantage of the fact that you can move your goalposts.

Now, since you haven't qualified your `Cells` reference (e.g. `Sheet1.Cells`) I'm going to be creating a new sheet with the data on.  (Always, always, **always** qualify your sheets, even if it's `ActiveSheet.Cells` or `Me.Cells`.  It helps you spot *so* many 'unexpected' errors before they happen)

Basically, we'll duplicate the input data, add a "Dates" column, then run down the rows filling it in.  If the Date is not the End Date, we duplicate the row and add 1 day - **this also makes the loop longer** - and when we reach the end of the loop we're done.

```
Sub DailyLines()
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lWorkingRow As Long, lEndRow As Long
    Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    'Copy Table1 to working sheet
    Union(sht.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange, _
        sht.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange).Copy Destination:=NewSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    NewSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist 'Convert table to range - this will mak it easier to work with
    NewSheet.Calculate
    NewSheet.Columns(8).Insert xlShiftRight 'Add a new column at H
    NewSheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Date" 'Add a header to the new column
    NewSheet.Calculate

    'This is where the processing starts
    lEndRow = NewSheet.Cells(NewSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find bottom row
    If lEndRow > 1 Then 'At least 1 row of data
        For lWorkingRow = 2 To lEndRow 'Step through rows
            'is this new data?
            If Len(NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 8).Value) < 1 Then 'Never processed this row before
                NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 8).Value = NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 9).Value 'Default to StartDate
            Else 'Not the first copy of the row
                NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 8).Value = NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 8).Value + 1 'Increment by 1 day
            End If
            'Have we finished with this data?
            If NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 8).Value + 1 <= NewSheet.Cells(lWorkingRow, 10).Value Then 'Not reached EndDate
                NewSheet.Rows(lWorkingRow).Copy NewSheet.Rows(lWorkingRow) 'Duplicate the row
                lEndRow = lEndRow + 1 'IMPORTANT!  We now need to process 1 more row of data!
            End If
        Next lWorkingRow
    End If

    'Tidy up
    Set NewSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems much more detailed. I'm wondering, does the first part is necessary? Is it possible to directly update in column #2 without adding a new sheet?

Comment: Moreover, "    Union(Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange, _
        Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange).Copy Destination:=NewSheet.Cells(1, 1)" seems to be source of error 424

Comment: Sorry - that should be `sht.ListObjects`, since that's the name of your worksheet.  `Sheet1` was my testing sheet.  And, I included the first part for 2 reasons:  First, your code did not have qualified ranges (so was producing data on `ActiveSheet`, which may-or-may-not be `Sht`) and also I have had... *issues*... working on Tables in the past (i.e. when they were first added to Excel) and prefer to turn them back into normal Ranges for operation where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, but unfortunately, the part I refered to in the last comment generates an error 91, do you have any idea why?

Comment: If Table1 does not have a header, then it will generate an error (change it to `sht.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Copy Destination:=NewSheet.Cells(1, 1)`) - otherwise, if you have renamed `sht` you will also get an error (it needs to point at the Worksheet that your data-table is on)

Comment: Ok but sht is not defined, what does it mean? Is it sheet 1?

Comment: You tell me:  Your originally posted code contains the line `LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count` - I'm just operating on that data table.